# How to get rollback operation detail through fn_dblog() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am searching for the detail of rollback operation using fn_dblog() function, but doesn't know the parameter value. 
I am running the below code:

```
SELECT
    [Current LSN],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Operation],
    [Transaction Name],
    [CONTEXT],
    [AllocUnitName],
    [Page ID],
    [Slot ID],
    [Begin Time],
    [End Time],
    [Number of Locks],
    [Lock Information]
FROM 
    sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE 
    Operation IN ('LOP_INSERT_ROWS', 'LOP_MODIFY_ROW', 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS',
                  'LOP_BEGIN_XACT', 'LOP_COMMIT_XACT')
```

So how can I get the detail of rollback operations?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using this on my Test database on SQL Server

Comment: This looks like SQL Server or Access, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: it is sql server,added tags based on fn_dblog function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LOP_ABORT_XACT  gives rolled back transactions..

```
select * from
sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
where
operation in
('LOP_ABORT_XACT')
```

Also note,using the above function on production databases is resource intensive and it also blocks log space reuse